# Hermitian metric on line bundle over the Grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, grassmannian

We know that the Grassmannian manifold $G(k,\mathbb{C}^n)$ can be embedded in the projective space $\mathbb{C}P^N$ for $N= {n\choose k}-1$ by the Plucker embedding $P$.

On $\mathbb{C}P^N$ we have the hermitian metric $h_a=\frac{|z_a|^2}{|z_0|^2+\cdots+|z_N|^2}$ over $U_a=\{z_a\neq0\}$ defined on the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1).$  See related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354803/hermitian-metric-on-l-mathcalo-mathbbpn1-over-the-projective-space).

Suppose we consider $P^* (\mathcal{O}(1))$ over the Grassmannian. How does the Hermitian metric look like here?

Any help/hints/ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: Almost a year after I asked this question: the answer is that it is very hard to find an expression for $h$. Because you really need to involve the Plucker relations to change the expression for $h_\alpha$-if that's practically possible.